# Combining fields and replacing text in Crystal Reports

Tags: google-maps, crystal-reports, replace, formula

I am a new Crystal Reports user and any help would be greatly appreciated. I am looking for a formula that allows me to combine two fields and also make a text replacement (mapping project).

For example, I am looking to combine an address and city into one field so I use the formula:

```
{Location.Address}+","+" "+{Location.City}.
```

This is usually sufficient except for a common street in town which is abbreviated in the records system. I need for the entries which read "24 SGE, Albany" to read "24 Stargate East, Albany" so the address can be interpreted by the mapping software.

I tried something like

```
{Location.Address}+","+" "+{Location.City}
```

and

```
Replace({Location.Address}," SGE"," Stargate East")
```

I got the error, `a boolean is require here`. So I am probably still far off. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Replace({Location.Address},"SGE","Stargate East") + ", " + {Location.City}
```